# Node.js Question on how to display the information successfully in html

Tags: node.js

The goal is show the subject enrolled by the students.

This line of code will display the data extracted from

```
mainContent.innerHTML = 
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="jumbotron my-5 bg-white">
                <h5 class="text-center">First Name: <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">${jsonData.firstName}</b> | Last Name: <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">${jsonData.lastName}</b> | Email: <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">${jsonData.email}</b> | Mobile No: <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">${jsonData.mobileNo}</b></h5>
                <table class="table text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Course Name </th>
                    <th>Enrolled On </th>
                    <th>Status </th>
                    <tbody>${userSubjects}</tbody>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </section>
        </div>
```

I was successfully able to display the data (subject name) on the console tab using console.log. However, extracting the code directly to the HTML tags on my JS doesn't allow it. It shows nothing or undefined.

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/users/details", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(jsonData => {
    if (jsonData) {
    
    let userSubjects = jsonData.enrollments.map(subject => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/${subject.courseId}`).then(res => res.json()).then(subjectData => {
            return (`
                    <tr>
                        <td>${subjectData.name}</td>
                        <td>${subject.enrolledOn}</td>
                        <td>${subject.status}</td>
                    </tr>
                `
            )
        })
    }).join("")

})
```

Comment: In your second code block, you're just  building an array of HTML into the `userSubjects` array, but don't show any code that does anything with that array in `userSubjects`.

Comment: That's what I thought actually. However, I'm having a problem fixing the issue. I tried multiple combination and other resources as well but didn't worked at all.  Actually I'm not getting the information from the 2nd fetch what I'm trying to accomplished is to get the subject name from the 2nd fetch but it just displaying undefined but it's showing on my console tab.

Comment: You say "displaying undefined".  But, you show no code that causes anything to be displayed in the current web page.  Is there code missing that you need to show us or are you asking how to take this HTML you created and insert it into the current web page?

Comment: ```let subjectName;
 let userSubjects = jsonData.enrollments.map(subject => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/${subject.courseId}`).then(res => res.json()).then(subjectData => {
   consol.log(subjectData)
   subjectName = subjectData.name
  })
  return (`
     <tr>
      <td>${subjectData.name}</td>
      <td>${subject.enrolledOn}</td>
      <td>${subject.status}</td>
     </tr>
    `
   )
 }).join("")``` It was prev like this. It shows on the console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `userSubjects` HTML inserted into your page, have to actually insert it into your page.  You don't show any of your page HTML so I'll just show a made-up example.  In addition, your `.map()` is created an array of promises so you have to wait for all those promises to resolve.

If you had this in your page:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then, you could insert your dynamically retrieved data and generated HTML into that div in the page like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/users/details", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(jsonData => {
    if (jsonData) {
    
    let userSubjectPromises = jsonData.enrollments.map(subject => {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/${subject.courseId}`).then(res => res.json()).then(subjectData => {
            return (`
                    <tr>
                        <td>${subjectData.name}</td>
                        <td>${subject.enrolledOn}</td>
                        <td>${subject.status}</td>
                    </tr>
                `
            )
        })
    });
    return Promise.all(userSubjectPromises).then(results => {
        const newHtml = results.join("");
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = newHtml;
    });
}).catch(err => {
     // do something with an error here
     console.log(err);
});
```

Summary of Changes:

1. Add `return` to the `fetch()` inside the `.map()` loop so that promise is returned to `.map()` and it will produce an array of promises
2. Use `Promise.all()` on the array of promises to wait for all the promises to be done and get the final result.  Return that promise so errors propagate up to the top level also
3. Insert the generated content into a `<div>` in your page.
4. Add a top level `.catch()` so you can catch any errors in your promises and log that or show an error to the user.

Comment: Awesome! This works for me. Just modified some of the codes. Thanks for explaining as well.